# R ggplot facet with non-disjoint classes

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Say I have five groups which are not disjoint (i.e. they are overlapping).  I would like to make a scatter plot of Var1 vs. Var2 for each of the classes.

More specifically, consider a data frame which has two columns Var1 and Var2, concatenated with five columns taking values 0 and 1, signifying each row's membership to each of the five classes.  If these classes were disjoint, I would simply use facet grid on a variable taking values 1 to 5, and problem solved.  But because they are overlapping, I'm not sure how to make such a plot.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why not include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data to make it more clear what exactly you have and what you want. This isn't a place for general plotting advice. Make sure you ask a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy using the `tidyr` package, in particular the `gather()` function from that package.

First I create a data frame that I think has the properties you want.  Note that I use dplyr and it's awesome [pipe syntax](http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html) (that's the `%>%` stuff below).

```
# packages we need
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

# an example data frame
df <- 
    data.frame(var1 = rnorm(30), 
               var2 = rnorm(30), 
               A = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 30, replace = T),
               B = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 30, replace = T),
               C = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 30, replace = T),
               D = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 30, replace = T),
               E = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 30, replace = T)
              )
```

The key step is rehape the data frame using `tidyr::gather()` so that each data point `(var1, var2)` is replicated five-fold, i.e. once for each column that is `gather`ed.  In addition to replicating the data in the columns not `gather`ed, the `gather()` function also creates two new columns.  The first of these I call `class` and will have values of either A, B, C, D, or E.  The second I call `is_in` and has a value of either TRUE or FALSE, depending on whether the corresponding data point is in the class referred to by the `class` column.

```
# reshape the data frame using dplyr 
df.reshaped <- 
    df %>% 
        mutate(index = row_number()) %>%  # number the data points
        gather(class, is_in, A:E) %>%     # repeat all (var1, var2) points 5x
        filter(is_in == TRUE) %>%         # keep only points you want
        select(-is_in)                    # the is_in column is now superfluous
```

The data is now ready for plotting.  Just to verify that our plot will show the same original data point in multiple facets, I put in a `mutate()` call above to number all the *original* (i.e. before gathering) data points by row number.  I'll plot using `geom_text()` and thus if we see the same number in different facets, the objective is achieved.

```
# plot the graph
df.reshaped %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = var1, y = var2, label = index)) +
        geom_text() +  
        facet_grid(.~class) +
        theme_bw()

ggsave('SO_39820087.png', width = 10, height = 4)
```

The resulting plot looks like this on my machine.

[image: Successful facet plot of non-disjoint classes]